# DB2 SQL Optimization suggestion

Tags: sql, optimization, db2

Please help me check the sql, is there any problem? can it be optimized? It will take long time to execute, but not always.

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM DB2INST3.VWQueue1_119 
WHERE inbasketName is not null
 AND userid1 is not null 
 AND nItemIndex is not null 
 AND string1 is not null 
 AND (F_BoundUser = ? OR F_BoundUser = ? )
 AND (F_Locked < 2) 
 AND ((inbasketName='PSIQUEUE1Index') AND (inbasketName='PSIQUEUE1Index'))
```

Got the snapshot as:

> Number of executions               = 12942  Number of compilations
>   = 1  Worst preparation time (ms)        = 6  Best preparation time (ms)         = 6  Internal rows deleted              = 0  Internal
>   rows inserted             = 0  Rows read                          =
>   1399262666    Total execution time (sec.microsec)= 3600.704315  Total
>   user cpu time (sec.microsec) = 2538.101110  Total system cpu time
>   (sec.microsec)= 0.191321

Comment: love that schema/table naming convention

Comment: This statement looks pretty simple and not much optimization can be done (F_Bounduser in there twice?).  Judging by your table name, you are selecting from a view...likely your performance issue is there.  @MitchWheat - Figure there is a VWQueue1_001 through VWQueue1_99999?

Comment: this is a physical table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplification of your query:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM DB2INST3.VWQueue1_119 
WHERE userid1 is not null and
      nItemIndex is not null and
      string1 is not null and
      (F_BoundUser in (?, ?) and
      (F_Locked < 2) and
      (inbasketName = 'PSIQUEUE1Index')
```

Here are the changes:

- The condition `inbasketName='PSIQUEUE1Index'` is mentioned twice.  Npt necessary.
- The condition `inbasketName is not null` is redundant, because the value is being compared to a string.

The only index that would most help is:  `VWQueue1_119(inbasketName, F_BoundUser, F_Locked)`.  If there is a large amount of other columns in the table, then adding `userid1`, `nItemIndex`, and `string1` would create a covering index so the original data pages are not touched.

Answer (score 0):

Conditions that use OR on an indexed column are notorious for causing the index to not be used. Fortunately there is a simple fix.

Change this:

```
AND (F_BoundUser = ? OR F_BoundUser = ? )
```

To this:

```
AND F_BoundUser IN (?, ?)
```

Although the two achieve exactly the same thing, the optimizer will (tend to) use an index with the IN() but not for the OR.

Besides, it's more elegant anyway.

This is something I've used successfully many times.

Comment: How much overhead will it take? Sometime it will take ~200ms to execute, does it make sense?

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense. Is one or both of the values `null`? Could the table be locked by another process?

Comment: I checked the locks, no issue.

Comment: Did you try the change? And did you check if you are sometimes sending nulls to the query?

Answer (score 0):

You can count on 0:

```
SELECT COUNT(0)
...
```

If the optimizator is not in a higher level, DB2 will prefetch the columns just to count them. With 0, DB2 will use other ways, like only indexes or stats.